# unlink projects from the dashboard in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-iam

I have several projects in my dashboard of an old company. However, I am as an "editor". Someone could tell me how to remove these projects from my dashboard. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot remove or unlink those projects if you are holding an **Project Editor** position, only the **Project Owner** can remove you from the project or a user that have a role of **Project IAM Admin**.

The best way to do is to ask the owner or the IAM Admin of the project and request that they remove you from their projects.